# Grab value of hidden input and assign to another input's value

Tags: jquery

I have an hidden input:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="hidden" /> 

 $('#hidden').before('<input type="text" id="mhidden" alt="decimal" value="" />');
 var val = $('#hidden').val();
 $('#mhidden').val(val);
```

In `<input type="text" id="mhidden" alt="decimal" value="" />` the value is empty in html but with `alert($('#mhidden').val(val));` has a value. Why the value of #mhidden is empty? I want to assign hidden input's value to #mhidden.

Thanks in advance

Comment: (a) `$('#mhidden').val(val)` returns a jQuery object. (b) It is empty in the HTML string because you wrote it like that. (c) `$('#mhidden').val(val)` will set the value. I don't understand your question, what is your problem? There does not seem to be any.

Comment: Seems to work fine (If you give #hidden a value anyway) - http://jsfiddle.net/v8MYh/

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('#mhidden').val(val));
```

This passes the value of the `val` variable to the `val()` function. This function acts as a getter/setter depending on whether a parameter is passed or not. What is being alerted is the return value for the setter version, which will be the jQuery object for `$('#mhidden')`.

Comment: I want to assign #hidden value to #mhidden. With above every thing is ok but in <input type="text" id="mhidden" alt="decimal" value="" /> value is empty. alert, print the value of #mhidden that grabs from #hidden

Comment: @Python: `<input type="text" id="mhidden" alt="decimal" value="" />` is a **string** in your code. Do you expect that your JavaScript code dynamically changes once you set the value? Maybe I misunderstand you. What is your concern you try to express with "*in <input type="text" id="mhidden" alt="decimal" value="" /> value is empty"*? Please be more clear.

Comment: @Felix Kling; condider <span id="mhidden"></span> . with var val = $('#hidden').val(); and $('#mhidden').text(val); there is no any text in span.

Comment: @Python: You will be able to see the text in the DOM. I still don't understand your problem. The HTML source will never be changed. Maybe this helps to understand it: http://jsfiddle.net/wkXVR/ If you use chrome or Firebug you can also right click on the element and select 'Inspect element'.

Comment: @python yes span will get the value of val,what exactly your looking here please clear

Answer (score 0):

you want to add the value of hidden to mhidden in html
you can try this

```
var val = $('#hidden').val();
$('#hidden').before('<input type="text" id="mhidden" alt="decimal" value='+val+' />');
```